# How to install OpenNI 1.x on a Mac?

Tags: kinect, openni

I have a Kinect for Windows and I would like to connect it to my Mac laptop with OSX 10.7.5.

I would like to use openNI as the driver.

OpenNI's website lists "OpenNI 2.1 Beta (OS X)" however the [source-code page](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2) does not list install instructions. Are they found someplace else?

There are install instructions on the [OpenNI 1.x github](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI) page and on [OpenNI 1.x Unstable branch](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/tree/unstable) page. The instructions for the two branches are slightly different, however neither have worked for me.

I originally had XCode 4.6 installed. Both instructions state they want XCode 4.3.2, which I installed, renamed XCode 4.6 and used "sudo xcode-select -switch" to switch between them.

Both instructions ask for "libusb-devel +universal" and in both cases I get:

```
Error: Please do not install this port since it has been replaced by 'libusb'.
Error: org.macports.configure for port libusb-devel returned: 
Please see the log file for port libusb-devel for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_libusb-devel/libusb-devel/main.log
Error: Processing of port libusb-devel failed
```

If I continue with the installation of "libusb +universal" instead, then the rest of the dependencies install fine (though I had to install GraphViz before Doxygen).

But then when I run: "./RedistMaker" I get a lot of warnings, though it does create a Final file. "sudo ./install.sh" runs fine and I'm guessing OpenNI is installed, but then I get a bunch more errors when trying to install Sensor.

Can anyone help tell where along the way should I have started to worry? Do I need to manually install libusb (which I have tried to do)?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Through the libfreenect mailing list, I found these two discussions about Kinect for Windows support [{1}](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/) and [{2}](http://answers.ros.org/answers/35351/revisions/)

Comment: I bought a Kinect for Xbox and OpenNI works fine with that.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the installation of OpenNI by running these instructions:

```
> sudo rm -f /opt/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
> sudo port clean libusb
> sudo port install libusb +universal
```

Basically the Mac install instructions need to be updated and should include a warning that the short install may leave files around that will need to be deleted before installing with port.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks... I think this should be selected as the correct answer...